# Controller name 'User' or 'Users' in CI 3

Tags: codeigniter

I had a code written in CI 2+ and now i am moving to CI 3 . I have one controller with the name of 'user' , when i try to access the function i always get this error

404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.

where as code is this

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

 class User extends CI_Controller {

public function t2()
{

    echo "test";
}

}
```

Where as if i change the controller name , i can access the function . Can anyone tell me whats the reason behind this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in CI 3 both controller file name & class name must be start with capital later .
so check it first.